# How react sideEffect detect value change?

Tags: reactjs

I'm just curious, how does sideEffect() detect change. For example:

```
React.useEffect(()=> {
 console.log('My val changed',number)
}, [number])
```

if `number` is a primitive type, then basically the it pass by value here, how `sideEffect` know if it changed?

UPDATED:

I see the replies, and i think ppl misunderstood my question. Here is the clarification: `useEffect` probably perform some sort of comparison like

```
useEffect(fun, array) {

  ... 

  // Compare value in array against some variable (probably from state)

  if (array[i] !== state[attributeName]) {
       // call func
  }
  ...


however, if a just a array of number, how does react know which attribute to compare with? 
}
```

Comment: React compares the previous and current values using [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is), which is similar to `===`

Answer (score 0):

It's use the `===` to check for equal, and this work for numbers comparation
[image]